# BBCode и textarea

Tags: php, bbcode

Вопрос: если я создам textarea и пользователь введет какие-нить bb-теги, ничего ведь не произойдет, если не написать функцию специальную для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос неконкретный. Если у вас просто на сайте некая форма, которую можно заполнить, на данные оттуда никуда вообще не поступают, то да - что там ни вводи, ничего страшного не будет. Если же данные обрабатываются в PHP, то в процессе обработки может появиться и уязвимость, например: [BBCode XSS Howto](http://jeffchannell.com/Other/bbcode-xss-howto.html).

Comment: а как защититься?